# TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not str

Tags: python, sql, database, tuples

I am trying to pull data from a database and assign them to different lists.
This specific error is giving me a lot of trouble "TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not str"
I tried converting it to float and etc, but to no success.

The code goes as below

```py
conn=MySQLdb.connect(*details*)
cursor=conn.cursor()
ocs={}
oltv={}
query="select pool_number, average_credit_score as waocs, average_original_ltv as waoltv from *tablename* where as_of_date= *date*"
cursor.execute(query)
result=cursor.fetchall()

for row in result:
    print(row)
    ocs[row["pool_number"]]=int(row["waocs"])
    oltv[row["pool_number"]]=int(row["waoltv"])
```

Sample output of print statement is as follows :

```
('MA3146', 711L, 81L)
('MA3147', 679L, 83L)
('MA3148', 668L, 86L)
```

And this is the exact error I am getting:

```
ocs[row["pool_number"]]=int(row["waocs"])
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

How do I solve this error?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Like the error says, `row` is a tuple, so you can't do `row["pool_number"]`. You need to use the index: `row[0]`.

Comment: Well, today Python 3 says 'tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str'. Slice notation like [start,stop,step] now is onboard. For more info look this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/1068013

Answer (score 54):

I think you should do

```
for index, row in result:
```

If you wanna access by name.

Answer (score 13):

I know it is not specific to this question, but for anyone coming in from a Google search: this error is also caused by a comma behind an object that creates a tuple rather than a dictionary

```
>>>dict = {}
>>>tuple = {},
```

### Tuple

```
>>>tuple_ = {'key' : 'value'},
>>>type(tuple_)
<class 'tuple'>
```

### Dictionary

```
>>>dict_ = {'key' : 'value'} 
>>>type(dict_)        
<class 'dict'>
```

Answer (score 11):

TL;DR: add the parameter `cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor` at the end of your `MySQLdb.connect`.

---

I had a working code and the DB moved, I had to change the host/user/pass. After this change, my code stopped working and I started getting this error. Upon closer inspection, I copy-pasted the connection string on a place that had an extra directive. The old code read like:

```
 conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="oldhost",
                        user="olduser",
                        passwd="oldpass",
                        db="olddb", 
                        cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
```

Which was replaced by:

```
 conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="newhost",
                        user="newuser",
                        passwd="newpass",
                        db="newdb")
```

The parameter `cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor` at the end was making python allow me to access the rows using the column names as index. But the poor copy-paste eliminated that, yielding the error.

So, as an alternative to the solutions already presented, you can also add this parameter and access the rows in the way you originally wanted. ^_^ I hope this helps others.

Comment: This error is returned: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'cursors'`

Comment: I am using PyMysql and this worked for me. Only change I needed to make was cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor . Then, I can use the column names. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Just adding a parameter like the below worked for me.

```
cursor=conn.cursor(dictionary=True)
```

I hope this would be helpful either.

Comment: You can also do this with Postgres: https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html

Comment: Is this for an old version? For sqlite3 the method to get rows represented as `dict`s is [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html?highlight=sqlite#sqlite3-howto-row-factory).

Answer (score 5):

The Problem is how you access `row`

Specifically `row["waocs"]` and `row["pool_number"]` of `ocs[row["pool_number"]]=int(row["waocs"])`

If you look up the [official-documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-fetchall.html) of `fetchall()` you find.

> The method fetches all (or all remaining) rows of a query result set and returns a list of tuples.

Therefore you have to access the values of rows with `row[__integer__]` like `row[0]`

Answer (score 1):

It's really late but OP's problem can be averted by unpacking the tuples in `result` in the for statement as the `result` is iterated over. Given `result` looks like `[('MA3146', 711L, 81L), ('MA3147', 679L, 83L), ('MA3148', 668L, 86L)]`, a solution could be as follows.

```py
result = [('MA3146', 711, 81), ('MA3147', 679, 83), ('MA3148', 668, 86)]
ocs, oltv = {}, {}
for pool_number, waocs, waoltv in result:
    ocs[pool_number] = int(waocs)
    oltv[pool_number] = int(waoltv)
```

---

In general, if you got a TypeError in the title (or more specifically, `TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str`), see if the following captures your case.

1. Iterate over a string and try to index a tuple. You probably never intended to iterate over a string and it should probably be a range/list etc. that returns integers.

   ```py
   tpl = tuple(range(10))
   for i in '10':
       tpl[i]           # <---- TypeError: tuple indices must be integers...


   for i in range(int('10')):
       tpl[i]           # <---- OK
   ```
2. Iterate over an `enumerate` object without unpacking. Enumerate returns a tuple of index and item pairs, which can be directly unpacked as you iterate over it.

   ```py
   lst = [{'a': 1}, {'a': 2}, {'a': 3}]
   for dct in enumerate(lst):
       dct['a']                       # TypeError


   for i, dct in enumerate(lst):
       dct['a']                       # OK
   ```
3. Index a namedtuple using a string. Even if namedtuple field names are defined using a string, namedtuples cannot be indexed using a string like a dict key. It can be indexed using integer indices or by field attributes.

   ```py
   from collections import namedtuple
   tpl = namedtuple('Tuple', 'x, y')(x=1, y=2)

   tpl['a']     # <---- TypeError
   tpl[0]       # <---- OK
   tpl.x        # <---- OK
   ```

Answer (score 0):

SQlite3 has a method named row_factory. This method would allow you to access the values by column name.

https://www.kite.com/python/examples/3884/sqlite3-use-a-row-factory-to-access-values-by-column-name

Comment: Welcome. Thanks for your contribution. Please edit to include the exact code necessary to implement the solution you suggest. As is, this may be considered (and would be welcomed as) a comment. As is, it's bordering on a Link-only response: not quite a complete, self-contained solution, as SO requires for Answers. When you have enough rep, you can add comments. Including reference links for follow up & explanations are hallmarks of quality answers, & tend to accumulate upvotes over time as users learn something to apply to their own coding issues. So, excellent. (code-only is discouraged)

Comment: Official documentation is here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html?highlight=sqlite#sqlite3-howto-row-factory

Answer (score 0):

I see that you're trying to identify by the name of a row. If you are looking for a specific column within the row, you can do [integer][column name]

For example, to iterate through each row and only pull out the value from the row with the column header of "pool number", you can do this:

```
for row in df_updated.iterrows():
    cell = row[1]['pool number']
    print(cell)
```

The code will then iterate through each row but only print out the value that matches the "pool number" column

Answer (score 0):

This problem had me stumped for a while too.  In order to have the sqlite cursor return dicts for each row, so you can use things like `row["waocs"]`, you need to specify the row_factory.  When connecting to the db, set the row_factory property of the connection:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
conn.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
```