# Is there any way to access SQL row data by the column name?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

After I used fetchall(), I got this error:

`TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not str`

very similar to this person's question, which I upvoted: [TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not str](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35359969/typeerror-tuple-indices-must-be-integers-not-str)

Just wondering... is there anyway I could get the data in such a way that would allow me to access data by writing `row["column_name"]` instead of `row[index]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sqlite interface includes a [row_factory](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Row) that enables addressing returned elements by column name.

Comment: Wow! This will be super helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Cursor returns one row as tuples of values, you need to convert the tuple row to map, e.g.:

```py
...
names = [desc[0] for desc in cursor.description]
for tuple_row in cursor.fetchall():
    row = {column: value for column, value in zip(names, tuple_row)}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access fields by name, instantiate the cursor as follows [1]:

```
db_cursor = db.cursor(dictionary=True)
```

By default the results are returned as a tuple, and an easy way to get the columns into variables is with list dereferencing:

```
db_result = db_cursor.fetchall()

for id, my_column, my_other_column, my_fourth_column in db_result:
    print(my_column)
```

[1] https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursordict.html