# Type error: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks

```
for table in tables:
    table_name = table['tableName']
   
    try:
        # Check if the table contains the column sys_filename
        if 'sys_filename' not in [x.name for x in spark.table(f"{schema_name}.{table_name}").schema]:
            print(f"Skipping table {table_name} because it does not contain the column sys_filename")
            continue
    except AnalysisException:
        print(f"Skipping table {table_name} because there is an error")
        continue
 
    print(f"Processing table: {table_name}")
```

I tried the above code in databricks and I get the following error.

```
Type error: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

How can I fix this?

---

edit:

pyspark code is different than python. " [TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not str](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35359969/typeerror-tuple-indices-must-be-integers-not-str) " is not a direct answer to this question.